# Finding all combinations of two products that never were ordered together

Tags: mysql, northwind

I have an array in SQL containing all orders and all products from those orders and I need to find all pairs of products that have never been ordered together in one order.

I started with something like this

```
SELECT a.orderid, a.productid, b.OrderID, b.ProductID from [Order Details] a cross join [Order Details] b
except  
SELECT a.orderid, a.productid, b.OrderID, b.ProductID from [Order Details] a cross join [Order Details] b
where a.ProductID=b.ProductID
```

but I don't know how to eliminate rest of the possible pairs so that I have only the ones I need left.

EDIT:
Modified the query a bit, went for a diffrent approach. I'm getting closer but still don't know how to get rid of repetitions like ab and ba

```
select p1.productid, p2.productid from products p1 join products p2 on p1.productid<>p2.productid
except
select a.productid, b.productid from [Order Details] a join [Order Details] b on a.ProductID<>b.ProductID
where a.OrderID=b.OrderID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join and filter on missed joins:

```
select p1.productid, p2.productid
from products p1
join products p2 on p1.productid < p2.productid
left join [Order Details] o1 on o1.productid = p1.productid
left join [Order Details] o2 on o2.productid = p2.productid
    and o2.OrderID = o1.OrderID
where o2.OrderID is null
```

This works because missed joins have all nulls in the row, and while the join condition is applied *during* the join, the where clause is applied *after* the join, so specifying that a joined column (that can't in reality be null) is null leaves only missed joins.

Another small but important point is the use of *less than* rather than *not equals* in the join condition when joining the product table to itself, which prevents products joining to themselves, but importantly prevents two products joining to themselves *twice* - which ultimately means more efficiency (half as many joins) and not having to use `distinct` to remove duplicate combinations.